# How do I report spam CV postings?

Tags: support, profile-page, spam

On these pages there is no "Report" button or other flagging UI.

https://stackoverflow.com/cv/jumanji-the-next-level-movies-free-stream

Comment: Use the "contact us" report. Someone managed to post a spam website on the stackoverflow domain

Comment: What are CV postings?

Comment: @JL2210 Curriculum Vitae, i.e. online résumés.

Comment: link is not working!

Comment: @Pavlos - It's been deleted (see below answer).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can contact the site, but you can also flag one of your own posts (since this user didn't post any question or answer) with a custom flag providing the link so non-employee moderators (like me) can do something directly without bothering the CMs.

Here, I just traced back to this user profile (which was also spamming about this same movie with avatar and text), and destroyed it (sorry, now you can't see that it was just spam for new Jumanji movie), deleting this spam page with it. Thank you for helping us fighting spam.